# getting uploaded file absolute path before uploading it on the server

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i  tried so to get uploaded file absolute path but i didn't find a solution : i know that i can't get the uploaded files absolute client side path. Limitation of the browser since that is considederd a security risk. so if i use p:uploadeFile simple mode :[ http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadSimple.jsf][1]

It will be an inputText field containing the absolute path of the selected project so can i retrieve it in my managed bean before clicking on the submit button (i mean uploading the file to the server the file to server )

```
<p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadController.file}" mode="simple"/>
 <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" 
   actionListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}"/>
```

And many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Some older browsers with security bugs may give you the full path on [`HtmlInputElement#value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement) in JavaScript, but all modern browsers only give the base filename back and others even prepend it with a fake path such as [`c:\fakepath`](http://davidwalsh.name/fakepath) in IE and Webkit browsers.

You shouldn't be interested in this information anyway. This is completely irrelevant to any self-respected business logic processing an uploaded file. Whatever functional requirement you thought to solve with this has to be solved differently.